# Incementing a variable when a button is pressed in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to integrate front end and back end and for that I need to send a variable with value incremeneted when a button is pressed to another python file. I am unable to increment the variable on preseeing the buton, so I need help
This is python file

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

    class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
        pass

    class LoginScreen(Screen):
       def press_read(self):
          app = App.get_running_app()
          self.ids.lbl1.text = "SharedVar is " + str(app.MY_NUMBER)



    class AdminApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.MY_NUMBER = 0
            return ScreenManagement()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        AdminApp().run()



    #:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
    #: import ew kivy.uix.effectwidget
    <ScreenManagement>:
        transition: FadeTransition()
        LoginScreen:


    <LoginScreen>:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
                Label:
                    text: 'I am LoginScreen'
                Label:
                    id: lbl1
                Button:
                    text: 'Read'
                    on_press:
                        root.press_read()
                        app.MY_NUMBER = app.MY_NUMBER + 1
                        root.ids.lbl1.text = 'SharedVar is ' + str(app.MY_NUMBER)
```

The bottom part is .kv file

Comment: Your code seams to work, although there is some wrong indentation there. But after fixing it, it does increment the variable (and the `Label`'s text.. What is exactly the question?

Comment: I need to pass the value of that increment variable to another python file but that is not happening

Comment: and I am getting this error I dont know why  File "C:/Users/ranjith garuda/PycharmProjects/untitled/admin.py", line 21, in <module>
     AdminApp().run()

Comment: If you want help for a problem, you must post a [mcve] that produces this problem, so that people can give you a solution. Your description is not enough..